# Passing state from Parent to Child using componentWillReceiveProps render many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing state from parent component to child component everything works fine but i'm getting undefined of the props that coming from parent component I think because I'm making `async` it take two sec before I setting state. When I'm setting TimeOut `this.props.check` for two sec in `componentDidMount` of Child component it works fine I got data

The problem here I don't feel ok to use `setTimeOut` so I decided to use `componentWillReceiveProps` it's worked but when any events in child component rendered the `componentWillReceiveProps` will re-render and I just need it to render only once.

I changed my code to be simple

Parent Component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      check: ''
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.call();
  }
  call = () => {
    //I'm making async here might take two sec
      this.setState({ check: 'received' })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Parent Component</span>
        <Child check={this.state.check}  />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
class Child extends Component {

  componentDidMount() { // this works fine and render only one time, this what I really wanna do but I don't like to use setTimeOut
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.props.check); 
    }, 2000)
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){ // this works but when any action happening this will re-render 
    if (nextProps.check !== this.props.check){
      console.log(this.props.check)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Child Component</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: I think I need to use `shouldComponentUpdate` with `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Please help these two answers not helped me

Answer (score 1):

If App's `state.check` might be `null` (because it is set asynchronously), you need to decide what you want to render during that time.

It might be that you don't want to render `Child` at all until `state.check` is set by using this in App's render method:

`{ this.state.check ? (<Child check={this.state.check}  />) : (<div>Loading...</div>) }`

Comment: I can't do this in my main code my original code my code looks like `<Child check={this.state.check}  notes={this.state.notes}  />`

Comment: Is there's another way to do this?

Comment: What do you actually want to happen while state.check is still null? What do you want to happen when it stops being null?

Comment: I don't want to send it if still null can we do it like this <Child { this.state.check && check={this.state.check} } />

Comment: Child always has to have *some* value for the check prop, it might be null or undefined or an actual value. Can you share any more info about what the user should actually see at any point in time?

Comment: The user will not see anything of this.state.check I don't want to use it inside return

Comment: When *do* you want to use it! There is no function which React will run for you when a random prop first gets a non-null value so if you want to run some code in Child the as soon as it spots check becoming non-null, you will have to handle the logic of that yourself, probably using `componentWillReceiveProps` as you have done. Note that this doesn't smell right but sometimes does have to happen. Also note that you should only use `shouldComponentUpdate` if you need the performance, react will cope just fine with a few pointless renders.